# CakePHP CSRF token mismatch when multiple forms on page

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I'm making a connection/registration form on a single page (using hiding elements to show one at a time) but there is a problem :

CakePHP returns a "CSRF token mismatch." in the method I passed in the 'url' option of the FormHelper for the registration.

The connection works, I'm using an ajax request for it and for reasons I have to use a classic redirection with the action for the registration

I checked both CSRF tokens, they're the same. But the registration form gives me an error.

Here is my method :

```
function registerCheck(){
    $data = $this->getRequest()->getData();
    dd($data);
}
```

Here is the form creation :

```
        <?= $this->Form->create(null, ['class'=>'ui form attached segment', 'type'=>'file', 'url'=>'/register']) ?>
```

And the HTML returned for both tokens :

```
<input type="hidden" name="_csrfToken" autocomplete="off" value="f118d0131f835f74665f9ad5a8ce03501abf8ad943131c09fe805da797215acad199f56d2f35442271382b88c046eab1602b85c1171d1aa52c36ab5bc94022c9">
```

Did I do anything wrong ?

Comment: Have you confirmed that the cookie is being correctly sent with your Ajax request?

Comment: The ajax request works fine, it's the form submit which doesn't work